# Control structure with truffle (assert and require)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, assert, require

When I'm trying to deploy contracts that contain `assert` and `require` using truffle I receive

```
Error: Undeclared identifier.
```

e.g:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Owned{

    address public owner = msg.sender;


    modifier onlyOwner(){
        assert(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function kill() onlyOwner{
        require(msg.sender ==owner);
        suicide(owner);
    }
}
```

I know that in the past truffle created its own `assert.sol` but surely they've updated it to be consistent with Solidity, and it doesn't explain why `require` also fail.

I'll highly appreciate any thoughts on how to overcome this issue.

Comment: it works perfectly on my machine. I'm able to compile and migrate the same code. which version of truffle are you using?

Comment: I'm using v3.2.1

Comment: I'm using truffle 3.2.5, try upgrading it.

Comment: added it as an answer, hope you can upvote it or accept it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works perfectly on my machine. I'm able to migrate and compile the given code.

The truffle version I'm using is - 3.2.5

Upgrade to this version, shall fix your issue.